# Android HttpURLConnection connection refused after few minutes in service when ui is not visible

Tags: java, android

I am working on small chat application which is working fine when the app is visible to user. A service class which get and send data using post every 5 second when aap is visible to user and works fine. But when app.is closed and service works in background for few minutes fine. After few minutes i.e. apprx 3 minutes it get conmection refused error and never fetch data from server until.the app is again visible to user. I cant find any solution. please help.me
I uses HttpURLConnection for posting data, and a Thread and timer for regular posting.

Comment: Android best pratices says:
 DO NOT USE MANUAL TIMED HTTP REQUESTS FOR CHATS APPLICATIONS, THIS WILL DRAIN THE BATTERY DRAMATICALLY, instead use the Google Push API

Answer (score 1):

Android suspend applications when they get into background, to make resources available for the foreground application. If you need to sync your data on the background you should use a Background Service or SyncAdapter.

Take a look at [Best Practices for Background Jobs](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html) and [Transferring Data Using Sync Adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

Comment: Thanks You. I thought the same, that Android suspend the connection when app.is no longer visible to user after few minutes. I will also try this. Thanks you again.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- Do not use manual timed HTTP requests for chats messages, its a very bad practice,
- But, if you want to keep this, use some new http request library like "[Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)" or "[OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)" (this is my favorite),
- If you want more professional and highly "best practice" stuff, use the Google's [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for chats apps, its use native google services for send messages to others apps, highly recommended.

Connection Refused can be your client (service) sending wrong data/values, wrong URL, wrong ports and wrong query, please post a piece of your code.

Comment: I m sure that app is sending correct data as early.. when app ui is not visible to user then requesting frequency from.server is change to 15 second. I traced the log, error occured when service wants to write data to outputstream. i will post code surely. And i will also try the above two method http request library. I tried to use GCM but it too tough and i failed. Thanks you.

Comment: @SyedMasoomRizvi hi, did you ever resolve this problem? i have an app that receives a push notification, which executes some code and then sends the result to server. It works fine when the app is visible to user, but when i hit the home key to but the app in the background it doesn't work. When in the background, the push is recived and the what ever code executes, but when i send the result back to server, via an IntentService, i get connection refused. thanks

Comment: @turtleboy Hello, This problem was resolved. My phone is Xiaomi Mi, And phone processes and background service is optimized by Mi, and its blocked my app after 2 minute. I resolved this issue by openning Setting>Batter Manager>App Uses and turned off the MIUI optimization, Now my app working great. If you are facing this issue tell me about your phone model. Or try to use Alarm Service to wakeup your service again in 5 minutes or any time(but more than 1 minute.).
I hope you should use Service instead of IntentService and onStartCommand(.....) return START_STICKY;

Comment: @SyedMasoomRizvi Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I'll have a look at what you have suggested. By the way, what is wrong with using IntentService?

Comment: @turtleboy Your welcome, IntentService closed itself once work get finished, but Service is use for performing long operation and it will start sticky(means get more priority than normal services.), such as performing regular communication with server.